# horizontal menu adding divs dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi im trying to add divs that are red between my sliding panels . My menu animates when you moueenter the menu item and a panel slides out, but between each panel i want to add/remove a panel dymaically. when i say remove i mean when you go backwards through the menu and the sliding panel retracts you then remove the last red div and when you mouseenter a menu item and the sliding panels exapand you add one red div(5px wide doesn't matter about the height) here is what i have so far. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gygk7/)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu-item').mouseenter(function () {
            var curr = $(this).closest('.container');
            var next = curr.next('.container');

            next.animate({ 'left': curr.position().left + curr.width() + 5 });

            if(curr.index() < ($('.container').length - 1)){
                here i need to add and remove a </div class="spacer"></div> to the right side
                of the current(var curr) div
            }

            var $index = curr.index() + 1;
            $('.container:nth-child(' + $index + ')').nextAll().each(function () {

                $(this).animate({ 'left': curr.position().left + curr.width() + 5 });

            });

        });
    });

.spacer
    {
        background-color:Red; width:5px; height:200px; position:absolute; z-index:1000;
    }

<table border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="menu" style="background-color:Black; width:2000px; height:300px;top:5px; left:50px  ">
                <div class="container" id="1" style="left:0; width:200px; height:220px; z-index:999; position:absolute; background-color:Aqua">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="2" style="left:0; width:200px; height:300px; z-index:998; position:absolute; background-color:Blue">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 4</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 5</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 6</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="3" style="left:0; width:200px; height:400px; z-index:997; position:absolute; background-color:Fuchsia">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 7</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 8</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 9</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="4" style="left:0; width:200px; height:500px; z-index:996; position:absolute; background-color:Green; float:left">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="5" style="left:0; width:200px; height:600px; z-index:995; position:absolute; background-color:Lime; float:left">
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
                    <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: HI again! I see the same question (i'm at home now... finally (:D) ) I'd really like to help you but you are soo unclear. And again. Your script is still the same. The divs open but.... too buggy. When I go hover-backwards with my mouse dhe div's did NOT retract correctly. Is that something you actually want or? Be more specific. And what is the purpose of the red divs?

Comment: the red divs are there to seperate content i saw a control i liked and wanted to copy it. i haven't found any bugs in it. it seems to me it retracts properly but if you can fix the bugs that would be good

Comment: how do i retract the divs without any bugs

Comment: I want my divs to slide out from left to right expand and retract and with each menu panel(.div.container) in between i want to add a red div how can i be more unclear

Comment: I'm playing around. I'll try to figure out something! With a .hover function should work great but than all the code changes.

Comment: ok do you're best and see what you come up with much appreciated

Comment: What browser do you use? in mozilla when i move my mouse away from the containers they stay still. But when i hover with my mouse the 2, container than the messy movements takes place.

Comment: using ie and google chrome in both browsers i don't get any problems are you getting problems in firefox

Comment: I tried fire fox and got no problems with the mouseenter functions it moves the divs correctly left and right

Comment: this is an intersting one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023472/jquery-hover-once

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding and removing multiple div dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911458/adding-and-removing-multiple-div-dynamically)

Comment: that was the other day hoping someone would be able to help me this time

Comment: I added something. Now I understand what whas bothering me. I expected as a user to see animation when I hover the DIV container, not only the text.

Comment: i put a time of 400 milliseconds on the animation and i noticed the div.containers don't animate at the same time slitly out of sync

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here... not shure if this is good but look here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gygk7/2/)

**E D I T**

Well here is another solution: [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/gygk7/7/)

Comment: it doesn't keep adding div elements to the panel that has slided out it just adds one

Comment: not quite what i was looking for if anyone else know what to do leave a answer or comment

Comment: thankyou for your help i got it working thanks heaps http://jsfiddle.net/WeYuM/2/